# Laravel - where to store files which I don't want to share with users

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, gitignore, file-storage

For example, I want to merge two .png files in one .png file, but I don't want to share those parts with user. Currently I am storing files in storage folder, but the problem is that storage folder is with .gitignore file as default. Of course I could allow to push it to git, but I suppose it's not a good idea, because there could be thousands of another files uploaded by the user. Now if I want to continue work from another computer I should move all my parts manually.

So what you could advice to me?

Comment: you can store on S3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store it anywhere you want in your application.

For example, you can make a folder in your projects root called `/uploads` and then use one of laravel [helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers) functions to specify where to save the file:

Example:

```
$save_path = base_path('uploads');
```

You can use the Laravel `File` Class to make sure the path exists with:

```
File::makeDirectory($save_path, $mode = 0755, true, true);
```

You will need to add `use File;` in the top of the file with all the class includes.

Later, to access said files you can make a [View Composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views) which you can add logic to in order to limit who can view the file.

Comment: That seems more accurate than my (now deleted) answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to protect your files so that nobody can access without permission store all file into **storage** folder. Don't put your file in public folder.